# How to redirect users to the pro version of my app(IOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have 2 versions of my app.. lite and pro.. in the lite version I wanna put a button that will redirect users to my pro app on the app store.. How can I do that? Thanks

and what would i do if i was to put a share button that consists of the link of the app that is not yet released...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the link of your pro app, then use `itms://` or `itms-apps://` to replace `http://`.

Use the button to launch this link. It will avoid redirects and land in app store

Comment: cheers.. i assume i have to release the pro version first.. right?

Comment: what if i need that link in my pro version? coz its not yet released so there is no link

Comment: before you submit the app,  you create it on iTunesConnect, you get AppID - plug it into the itms link and the URL will work once the app is approved and in the app store.